# Nginx proxy_pass redirect to URL from query string

Tags: nginx, query-string, proxypass

I'm using Nginx and trying to redirect using proxy_pass to a URL that comes as a query string. I also want to avoid passing any other parameters to that URL.

This is the url I'm sending to the proxy:
http://10.10.10.10/proxydownload?url=http://www.test.com/d/guid/download&session=123

This is what I have in the nginx.conf:

```
location /proxydownload {
    proxy_pass $arg_url;
}
```

However, this is generating a 502 error, and I don't know why. According to the logs, $arg_url contains "http://www.test.com/d/guid/download", and that's the url I want to hit. 
I tried to hardcode the URL in proxy_pass and it worked:

```
location /proxydownload {
    proxy_pass http://www.test.com/d/guid/download;
}
```

Is there's something incorrect on the way I use $arg_url?

Comment: You should read [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/298392/how-to-use-nginx-as-a-http-https-proxy-server), looks like you're trying to implement a web proxy with nginx.

Comment: @user3780601, is there anything else that's missing from the two answers?  If not, please accept the best answer.  If you perform no action within the next couple of hours of the grace period, at least half of the bounty amount will be irrevocably lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because when you hardcode the value passed to http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass, without using any variables, then the default resolver, from [/etc/resolv.conf](http://mdoc.su/o/resolv.conf), is used at the time that the configuration is parsed and loaded — any subsequent changes in the IP address won't be picked up.

If, instead, you use variables, then you must also use the http://nginx.org/r/resolver directive to specify a resolver.  [Note that you can still use a DNS name when specifying a resolver](//stackoverflow.com/a/51227227/1122270), but keep in mind that such name will likely only be resolved once, at configuration load or reload time.  Of course, as per Dayo's answer, it's best to use a local DNS resolver for best security, but if, for example, you know that all your domains will be delegated to a certain authoritative nameserver, for example, including `ns2.he.net.`, then you might as well simply specify such a server as the `resolver`.

Speaking of security, however, it doesn't seem like a very good idea to trust user's input for specification of the upstream server.  This is one of these things that greatly increases the attack vector — both for using your server as a free `proxy_pass` to anywhere on the internet (potentially exhausting your resources from being available for valid use), as well as by a malicious actor to try to exploit a potential vulnerability in your nginx by a malicious upstream server controlled by the attacker (take a look at [CVE-2013-2070](http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx-announce/2013/000114.html), for example).

Answer (score 0):

Using  `proxy_pass` with variables is a complex and poorly documented minefield.

I assume your 502 error was "no resolver defined to resolve ..."

In this case, you need to install bind (yum install bind) and add a resolver to your config.

```
location /proxydownload {
    resolver 127.0.0.1 [::1];
    proxy_pass $arg_url;
}
```

Using an external resolver such as Google's `8.8.8.8` would work without the need for bind but there are [Potential Security Issues](http://blog.zorinaq.com/nginx-resolver-vulns/).